# Can BreakIterator be made to recognise "'tis" as a word

Tags: java, string, text, apostrophe, word-boundary

Using a `BreakIterator.getWordInstance()`, the text `"can't"` is considered one "word"

A little experimentation shows that while an apostrophe's *within* a word is considered part of the word; apostrophes at either end are considered as being separate from the word - that is a word boundary is reported between the apostrophe and the letters.

This precludes words like `"'tis"` and `"dogs'"` from being considered "words", even though they are spelled correctly.

Is there a way to correct this behaviour, or is this a bug?